# How to prevent the trigger from sending an error if the table does not exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I wrote trigger after deleting a row (user) to drop the table that has the name composed from ID of this row (but not every ID has a table), I don't like to throw exception in code if the table does not exist!

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER AfterDeleteUser
            ON usersProject
            FOR DELETE
            AS DECLARE @IDres VARCHAR(50),
            @tablename VARCHAR(50)


            SELECT @IDres = ins.IDressource FROM DELETED ins;
            set @tablename = concat('MSG_', @IDres);
            
            SET NOCOUNT ON;
            DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

            SET @Sql = N'DROP TABLE '+QUOTENAME(@tablename)
        
                EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql;
            go
```

I get this error when the table does not exist!

> Msg 3701, Niveau 11, État 5, Ligne 7
>
> Cannot drop the table 'MSG_', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: You should use `SysName` instead of `VARCHAR(50)` for object names

Comment: In SQL Server 2016 you can use: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ...

Comment: the trigger works well when table exits

Comment: you should not have print statement in the trigger code. It is bad design.

Comment: sql server 2017, I tested DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  , it works well now , but the problem if make migration for database on an other sql server version that will not work

Comment: @ManelHkiri Well, you have another option which will works well in both versions.

Comment: BTW, `SELECT @IDres = ins.IDressource FROM DELETED ins;` is not what you think. What if there is >1 rows deleted???

Comment: @Sami it's one row deleted bcz IDressource is unique

Comment: Alright, maybe **[`this demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ffae3339304319a2eb9ae8a9c6b11744)** can help you to understand @ManelHkiri.

Comment: @Sami thank you for your help, I liked the demo, Shukran!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From SQL Server 2016 on, you could use the syntax:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [Tablename]
```

For older versions you could do:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tablename', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE tablename;
```